# How do you load g4 grammars with inmemantlr?

Tags: antlr4

Sticking to the sample code in the [readme](https://github.com/julianthome/inmemantlr/blob/master/README.md) of [inmemantlr](https://github.com/julianthome/inmemantlr), I can't get any of the [grammars-v4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) to work. When initializing `GenericParser` with [java8.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/Java8.g4), for instance, it says:

```
error(50): :1426:3: syntax error: 'lL' came as a complete surprise to me while matching a lexer rule
error(50): :1448:3: syntax error: '1-9' came as a complete surprise to me while matching a lexer rule
error(50): :1469:7: syntax error: 'xX' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for lexer rule element
error(50): :1479:3: syntax error: '0-9a-fA-F' came as a complete surprise to me while matching a lexer rule
error(50): :1505:3: syntax error: '0-7' came as a complete surprise to me while matching a lexer rule
error(50): :1521:7: syntax error: 'bB' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for lexer rule element
error(50): :1531:3: syntax error: '01' came as a complete surprise to me while matching a lexer rule
error(50): :1567:3: syntax error: 'eE' came as a complete surprise to me while matching a lexer rule
error(50): :1577:3: syntax error: '+-' came as a complete surprise to me while matching a lexer rule
error(50): :1582:3: syntax error: 'fFdD' came as a complete surprise to me while matching a lexer rule
error(50): :1593:7: syntax error: 'xX' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for lexer rule element
error(50): :1603:3: syntax error: 'pP' came as a complete surprise to me while matching a lexer rule
error(50): :1622:4: syntax error: ''\\\r\n]\n\t;\n\n// §3.10.5 String Literals\n\nStringLiteral\n\t:\t'"' StringCharacters? '"'\n\t;\n\nfragment\nStringCharacters\n\t:\tStringCharacter+\n\t;\n\nfragment\nStringCharacter\n\t:\t~["\\\r\n]\n\t|\tEscapeSequence\n\t;\n\n// §3.10.6 Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals\n\nfragment\nEscapeSequence\n\t:\t'\\' [btnfr"'\\' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for lexer rule element
error(50): :1660:3: syntax error: '0-3' came as a complete surprise to me while matching a lexer rule
error(50): :1735:3: syntax error: 'a-zA-Z$_' came as a complete surprise to me while matching a lexer rule
error(50): :1737:3: syntax error: '\u0000-\u007F\uD800-\uDBFF' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for lexer rule element
error(50): :1740:2: syntax error: '\uD800-\uDBFF' came as a complete surprise to me while matching a lexer rule
error(50): :1746:3: syntax error: 'a-zA-Z0-9$_' came as a complete surprise to me while matching a lexer rule
error(50): :1748:3: syntax error: '\u0000-\u007F\uD800-\uDBFF' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for lexer rule element
error(50): :1751:2: syntax error: '\uD800-\uDBFF' came as a complete surprise to me while matching a lexer rule
error(50): :1766:7: syntax error: ' \t\r\n\u000C' came as a complete surprise to me while matching a lexer rule
error(50): :1774:14: syntax error: '\r\n' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for lexer rule element
```

The line producing the output above is simply:

`this.parser = new GenericParser(grammarFile);`

where `grammarFile` is the [java8.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/Java8.g4) file.

Ignoring the messages above and going on with the following:

```
this.parser.setListener(new ParserListener());
this.parser.compile();
```

fails with this exception:

```
 org.snt.inmemantlr.exceptions.CompilationException: No string code pipeline availabe
    at org.snt.inmemantlr.GenericParser.compile(GenericParser.java:313)
```

Using [version 1.4 of inmemantlr](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.julianthome/inmemantlr/1.4) (for compatibility with Java 8). Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Given it's a library not used by a lot of people, you'd probably have more luck raising an issue on the GitHub repo. If you get an answer there, you can always post it here on SO as well. Good luck!

Comment: @BartKiers Thank you, done. [Issue #34 on GitHub](https://github.com/julianthome/inmemantlr/issues/34).